# How do I compile Python 3.2 on NetBSD? Error code 127

Tags: compiling, python, netbsd

I'm getting strange errors when I try to compile Python 3.2 on NetBSD 5.1:

```
python ./Objects/typeslots.py < ./Include/typeslots.h > ./Objects/typeslots.inc
python: not found
*** Error code 127
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to compile Python in the usual fashion:

```
./configure
make
su
make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you have to `touch` some files during the `make` process. When make quits with this Error 127, run:

```
touch ./Include/typeslots.h
touch ./Objects/type
touch ./Objects/typeslots.py
make
```

Inside of the Python source directory.

It will complain a second time:

```
./Python/makeopcodetargets.py ./Python/opcode_targets.h
env: python: No such file or directory
```

Again, just `touch` the offending files and run `make` again.

```
touch ./Python/makeopcodetargets.py
touch ./Python/opcode_targets.h
make
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now (since May 2012) in pkgsrc -- `lang/python32`